# Different speeds for one function JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function which animates an object, however later on I decided to add some other objects which should animate with the same parameters but different speeds. I would not like to copy paste the written function but don't know how to call it with different speeds. Could you please help me to do so?

```
var moveObjects = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#object1").animate({
            left: -110 + "%"
        }, 15000, "linear", function() {
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        });
        $("#object1").animate({
            left: 110 + "%"
        }, 15000, "linear", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        });
    }, 1000);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveObjects();
});
```

Comment: `moveObjects = function(speed)` ... and .. `setInterval(function() { .. }, speed); ` ??

Comment: Yes, great!!! Post your answer and I will mark it as correct one :) Thanks!

Comment: do _not_ mix `setInterval` with jQuery animations - they'll fall out of sync

Comment: Its ok, the answers below are right too. Glad to help.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks again! :)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I am stuck in further step, when I call the function for different objects like so $(document).ready(function(){ $('#anobject').moveObjects(5000)});  it doesn't work, devtool says that the "moveObjects" is not a function :((( How do I call the function for multiple objects?

Comment: Try `$.fn.moveObjects = function(speed) { /* Use $(this) */ }; `

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I did not get it  :( Ok, never mind.. Thanks again for the effort :)

Comment: I mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/skpv94yg/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks, but again I did not get how can I use what you offer to my function. I mean where to put "this". Please see the whole picture of what I want to get. There are two object which now move with same speed, I need make them different. http://jsfiddle.net/skpv94yg/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skpv94yg/4/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown now much more clear :)) Thanks you so much for your time and efforts! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the hard coded values with arguments to the function:

```
var moveObjects = function(animSpeed, delay) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#object1").animate({
            left: -110 + "%"
        }, animSpeed, "linear", function() {
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        });
        $("#object1").animate({
            left: 110 + "%"
        }, animSpeed, "linear", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        });
    }, delay);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveObjects(15000, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var moveObjects = function(intervalTime) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#object1").animate({
            left: -110 + "%"
        }, 15000, "linear", function() {
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        });
        $("#object1").animate({
            left: 110 + "%"
        }, 15000, "linear", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        });
    }, intervalTime);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveObjects(); //<--Place the speed here that you want for each.
});
```